# Missing watch face activity template in a new project (Android Studio Giraffe)

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm creating a new Watch Face project using Android Studio Giraffe, but I can't find this kind of activity template.

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA3z2.png)

Can someone tell me how I install this activity?

I've tried researching this issue on the Android developer pages but I didn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

IDK why, but in the latest 2022 release they removed the watch face template (but on the website they are talking about this template LOOL). In Dolphin 2021.3.1 we still have this activity YEA

This GitHub page https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples provides some additional templates

Comment: Thanks for your response, not finding the watch face template and going to the website manual where the watch face template is referenced was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

any further knowledge on that? I am also wondering why it is not here anymore